# How to query documents with null values MongoRepository Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I couldn't initialise the value to be false in Spring Data MongoDB, so in my query, I want to search documents with field set to false or null.

The following snippet doesn't seem to work:

```
@RestResource(rel = "findInactiveOrders", path = "findInactiveOrders")
Order findByIdAndIsActiveFalseOrIsActiveNull(@Param("id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can achieve such query using Spring data method name. Since your query will be evaluated as `_id == "id" AND isActive == false OR isActive == null` and not `_id == "id" AND ( isActive == false OR isActive == null )`.

If by chance `isActive` can only be `true`, `false` or `null`, you could try

```
@RestResource(rel = "findInactiveOrders", path = "findInactiveOrders")
Order findByIdAndIsActiveNot(@Param("id"), true)
```

Otherwise, you will need to use other query method provided by Spring data mongodb such as `MongoTemplate` helper class or `@Query` annotation.

**@Query annotation**

```
@RestResource(rel = "findInactiveOrders", path = "findInactiveOrders")
@Query("{$and: [{'_id': :#{#id}}, $or: [{ 'isActive':false}, {'isActive': null}]]}")
Order findByIdAndIsActiveNot(@Param("id"))
```